# Evaluating Integrals (by Trigonometric Substitution)

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve this

[image: integral]

but I'm not sure which one is right (or if both are incorrect). Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your first method is fine. The second is not

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your first approach,

\begin{align}
\int \frac{\sqrt{9^{x}+1}}{3^{x}}\, {\rm d}x&=\int \frac{\sqrt{u^{2}+1}}{u^{2}\ln 3}\, {\rm d}u,\quad u=3^{x},\\
&=\frac{1}{\ln 3}\int \csc^{2} t \sec t\, {\rm d}t,\quad u=\tan(t),\\
&=\frac{1}{\ln 3}\int (\cot^{2}t +1)\sec(t)\, {\rm d}t,\\
&=\frac{3^{-x}}{\ln 3}\left(3^{x}\ln(\sqrt{9^{x}+1}+3^{x})-\sqrt{9^{x}+1}\right)+C
\end{align}
for some constant $C\in \mathbf{R}$. 
I'll let you fill in the details.

Comment: Hi, I'm just a bit confused. how did it become ∫csc^2(t) sec(t) dt?

Comment: @dgadgdgsdg No problem. If $u=\tan(t)$ so $du=\sec^{2}tdt$. Then $\sqrt{u^{2}+1}=\sqrt{\tan^{2}t+1}=\sec t$ and $t=\tan^{-1}u$. I hope it's clear now.